# Sylius: How to create controller extends from ResourceController?

Tags: symfony, resources, sylius

I want to create a custom controller:

```
class ApiappController extends ResourceController
```

And I added the route:

```
sylius_api_mobile_user_show:
  path: /{id}
  methods: [GET]
  defaults:
    _controller: sylius.controller.apiapp:showAction
```

But when I call this link, it has always this error message:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct() must be an instance of Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\Configuration, none give
```

How can I define the config ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You also need to create the configuration for the resource/controller.

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        acme:
            classes:
                controller: Acme\FooBundle\Controller\BarController
```

Your route configuration

```
acme_foo_bar_index:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: acme.controller.bar:indexAction
        _sylius:
            template: AcmeFooBundle:Bar:index.html.twig
            permission: false
```

Make note that the controller name is based on name in the resource configuration

The relevant doc page is here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/general/overriding_controllers.html